# Trello cards menu

Tags: trello

I have 3 boards, each with a number of non-empty lists.

When I click on the Cards link (on the right hand menu), the page flips to show Cards page, with "sorting by board on top".
However, it only shows one of the boards and two cards from that board. I can't figure what is the logic behind it.

How does it decide which of the 3 boards to show and for that board, which cards to show?

Answer (score 1):

The cards view page will show cards from all boards, but only if you have been assigned as a member of that card (you're avatar is displayed on it).